# Issue with Texture Painting, confused on what to do next

Tags: materials, texture-painting, normal-map, shader-nodes, texture-paint-mode

So I'm currently trying to texture paint a couple of white stitches onto a mesh where I've already sculpted and baked them as a normal map. I have mixed the stitches one with the original one for the material and now I'd just like to be able to color the stitches themselves to make them pop however when I try to do so, it doesn't work.

[image]

I assume I'm missing some vital step along the process that's gonna let me do that but I just don't know what it is. Below is the current node setup for the material.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you paint some color on your base color texture, the color information is dismissed, because the following color ramp only takes into account the value of every pixel, and outputs a shade of orange.

One way to solve is to bake the base color orangy texture, then plug it directly in the base color input of the Principled BSDF shader and perform the texture painting on it.

Another method is to create  a new base color texture, paint it all black, except for white stitches, then play with a color mix node AFTER the orangy color ramp.

Comment: +1 Another variation for the second method to mix after the color ramp would be to have a transparent image texture instead of black, then paint opaque stitches in whatever color you desire (maybe even different colors or gradients etc.) and mix them by the alpha channel.